# Pyglet, player, next song

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, audio, pyglet

I'm trying to play songs in Python 3 via pyglet. I can play and stop a song, but when I try to play the next song it produces an error. [I followed these instructions.](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/controlling_playback.html) I will do the program in tkinter.

my code:

```
import pyglet
import glob
from tkinter import Tk, Button
songs=glob.glob("*.mp3")
player=pyglet.media.Player()
def play_song():
    global player
    for i in range(len(songs)):
        source=pyglet.resource.media(songs[i])
        player.queue(source)
    player.play()
def pause_song():
    player.pause()
def next_song():
    player.next()

window=Tk()
play_=Button(text="play", command=play_song)
play_.pack()
pause_=Button(text="pause", command=pause_song)
pause_.pack()
next_=Button(text="next", command=next_song)
next_.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Fany\Dokumenty\Hudba\Sabaton\2012 - Carolus Rex\py.py", line 15, in next_song
    player.next()
 AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having a similar issue with pause()

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following change to your next_song()

```
def next_song():
    player.next_source()
```

**Reason**
Refer this page
https://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/media/pyglet.media.Player.html#pyglet.media.Player.time

You will find that *next()* is "Deprecated" and is recommend to use *next_source()* rather

HTH

**PS** When I tested you snippet on my machine it worked.

Answer (score 0):

YOU can use  os module ,or just see the process of playing next song ,i thought it may help for many people, who may using os module or anyother, to play next song use global variable ,its important

```
from tkinter import *
import os


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("music player ")
Label(root, text="MUSIC PLAYER").pack()
i=0

def prev():
   pass
def paly():
    music_dir = 'D:\songs'
    songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
    print(songs)
    os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
def nxt():
    global i
    music_dir = 'D:\songs'
    songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
    print(songs)
    os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[i]))
    i=i+1
f1=Frame(root).pack()
Button(f1,text="prev",command=prev).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30)
Button(f1,text="play/pause",command=paly).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30)
Button(f1,text="next",command=nxt).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30)


root.mainloop()
```